# Tools to detect when a weak encryption algorithm is being used

Tags: encryption

Every time I've joined a new company I've found that there is an in-house encryption algorithm in place to work with passwords and such. And every time it's just some kind of substitution cipher method. Apparently people think that an in-house algorithm must be safer just because it is custom.

Anyway, I once met a guy who was doing security consulting in one of these companies and by using one of his tools he had no problem cracking one of the passwords to get into our system. Do you know of specific tools that can do this? I'd love to show my current coworkers just how easy it is to break these types of algorithms.

Comment: i need help sending my 25 million dollars to your account... please make a small deposit in my account to set up the links...

Comment: Can you be any more specific? What algorithm? What password system? What context can you give us?

Comment: @Blender: I'm specifically talking about in-house algorithms. For example, replacing each character with another one calculated from the original ([subsitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)). So, the algorithm isn't known but is certainly weak.

Comment: @Randy: I'm talking about cipher analysis software. Nothing fishy about that.

Comment: I don't really know, seems to be an edge case, but: Wouldn't this question be a better fit for Serverfault or SuperUser? I bet the guys over there use that type of software more often than the average developer. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Frequency analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) is one of the basic techniques to use against substitution ciphers.

Comment: I doubt any security system uses substitution ciphers.

Comment: That's precisely my point. I've seen it used in the companies where I've worked.